# Error with method contains Vector java

Tags: java, vector, contains

I want to make a phone book.

Executing and putting two identical objects is not recognized in the "`while`" loop with the method "`contains(OBJECT)==TRUE`".

Where did my code go wrong? Appreciate any help thanks!

**Main**

```
public class MainRubrica {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyb= new Scanner(System.in); 

        System.out.print("Inserire il numero di contatti da aggiungere: ");
        int nM= keyb.nextInt(); 

        Vector<Contatto> rubrica = new Vector<Contatto>(20, 5);

        for(int i=0;i<nM;i++){
            System.out.println("\nContatto n."+(i+1));
            Contatto c =new Contatto();
            c.inserimento();
            while(rubrica.contains(c)==true) {
                System.out.println("Il contatto è già presente");
                c.inserimento();
            }
            rubrica.addElement(c);
        }

        for(int i=0;i<nM;i++){
            System.out.println("\nContatto n."+(i+1));
            System.out.println(rubrica.elementAt(i));
        }
```

Class Contatto

```
public class Contatto {
    //attributi
    private String nome; 
    private String cognome;
    private String numeroTel;

    //costruttore di default
    public Contatto(){
        nome=""; 
        cognome="";
        numeroTel=""; }

    //costruttore con parametri
    public Contatto(String nome, String cognome, String numeroTel){
        this.nome=nome; 
        this.cognome=cognome; 
        this.numeroTel=numeroTel; }

    //metodo set
    public void setNome(String nome){
        this.nome=nome; }
    public void setCognome(String congnome){
        this.cognome=cognome; }
    public void setNumeroTel(String numeroTel){
        this.numeroTel=numeroTel; }

    //metodo get
    public String getNome(){
        return nome; }
    public String getCognome(){
        return cognome; }
    public String getNumeroTel(){
        return numeroTel; }

    //metodo inserimentoContatto
    public void inserimento(){
        Scanner keyb= new Scanner(System.in); 
        System.out.println("Nome: ");
        nome=keyb.nextLine(); 
        System.out.println("Cognome: ");
        cognome=keyb.nextLine();  
        System.out.println("Numero di telefono: ");
        numeroTel=keyb.nextLine(); 
    }

    public String toString(){
        return "Nome: "+nome+"\nCognome: "+cognome+"\nNumero di Telefono: "+numeroTel; 
    }

}
```

Comment: What did it do wrong though? What was the expected result and the actual result?

Comment: Serious question: who or what told you to use `Vector`? It's use has been [discouraged since Java 1.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html), which was [released in 1998](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#J2SE_1.2).

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish, but the reason you aren't ever getting into the while loop is that you haven't overridden the Object.equals method for your Contatto class.  Here is the definition of Object.equals:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return (this == obj);
}
```

Using this definition of the "equals" method, it doesn't matter whether all the fields have equivalent values.  The two objects are not equal unless they are the same object.

Overriding the equals method in your Contatto class will address this.  When you do that, you also need to override the Object.hashCode method so as to maintain the contract for that method as well (equal objects must have equal hash codes).  I like to use the [Apache Commons Lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) library for this.  Using that library, you would add something like these methods to your Contatto class:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(final Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) {
        return true;
    } else if (obj instanceof Contatto) {
        final Contatto rhs = (Contatto) obj;
        return new EqualsBuilder().append(getNome(), rhs.getNome())
                .append(getCognome(), rhs.getCognome())
                .append(getNumeroTel(), rhs.getNumeroTel())
                .isEquals();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return new HashCodeBuilder().append(getNome()).append(getCognome())
            .append(getNumeroTel()).toHashCode();
}
```

Without the Apache Commons Lang library (should be equivalent to what the library is doing):

```
@Override
public boolean equals(final Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) {
        return true;
    } else if (obj instanceof Contatto) {
        final Contatto rhs = (Contatto) obj;
        return Objects.equals(getNome(), rhs.getNome())
                && Objects.equals(getCognome(), rhs.getCognome())
                && Objects.equals(getNumeroTel(), rhs.getNumeroTel());
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 17 * 37 + getNome().hashCode();
    hash = hash * 37 + getCognome().hashCode();
    hash = hash * 37 + getNumeroTel().hashCode();
    return hash;
}
```

After you add those methods, or implementations of them that match your definition of equality between two Contatto instances, then you should see your code entering that while loop if you input equivalent Contatto objects.

Comment: Thanks! But I always error on equalsBuilder()  and HashCodeBuilder(). I have to import something?

Comment: Yes.  To use this specific solution, you'll need to include the Apache Commons Lang library in your build and you'll need to import `org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.EqualsBuilder` and `org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.HashCodeBuilder`.  If you prefer not to use this library, there are plenty of information out there about how to appropriately write `equals` and `hashCode` methods.

Comment: Could you give me an example without using this library thanks?

Comment: Edited to add an example without Apache Commons Lang library.